# Can I use a Gridseed ASIC miner with a Raspberry Pi 3 B?

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-setup, gridseed

Could I use the [Gridseed ASIC miner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J4XPKJU) with a Raspberry Pi B? If so, how?